# jquery (over)writes DOM instead of div

Tags: jquery, html

I have an index.html and a linked script. My jQuery code that should .html write content into a div from the linked script, however it rewrites the entire page. The .text works great, however the content that has to be written contains a script.

index.html

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="copyright" name="copyright">
   </div>
</body>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.copyright").html("&copy; <script> new Date().getFullYear()>2010&&document.write(new Date().getFullYear()) </script> myName");
});
```

The current result is a webpage that loads "2017". But it should return "© 2017 myName". Does anyone know how to fix this? Or if it is at all possible to write both html and scripts with the .html method?

Comment: why dou you use <script> in html()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var a = (new Date().getFullYear()>2010) ? new Date().getFullYear() : "2010"
        $("div.copyright").html("&copy;"+ a + " myName");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="copyright" name="copyright">

        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: if it worked for you , please consider accepting this answer so that other users know it has been solved

Comment: Sure, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `document.write` in your  insert with jQuery.
Why you are creating a new script??

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(new Date().getFullYear()>2010){ $( "div.copyright" ).write(new Date().getFullYear());}
});
```

If you need the script tag you could use `this` in javascript(not tested sorry)
Or `$(this)` in jQuery (another time not tested)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant document.html . I wrote too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
in your html :

```
<div>
&copy;
<span id="copyright">

</span>
 myName
</div>
```

And in your js :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  if(new Date().getFullYear()>2010){ $( "#copyright" ).write(new 
  Date().getFullYear());}
     });
```

Comment: changing my js ... can you try again ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by hasan

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var a = (new Date().getFullYear()>2010) ? new Date().getFullYear() : "2010"
        $("div.copyright").html("&copy;"+ a + " myName");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="copyright" name="copyright">

        </div>
</body>
```